# Excel 365: .xlsb/.xlsm files gain significant bloat

Tags: excel, xlsm

I recently experienced "Catastrophic Failure" on a large .xlsm file. Its size was >165 MB. It was so damaged that I could not view or edit VBA and I could not copy any worksheet to a new workbook.

I manually recreated it. First, I built all the Data Connections to establish their sheets which were required by the "working" worksheets. Then, I manually rebuilt each working sheet, copying the headers and table names (I created tables with 1 header and 1 data row in each), and copied the formulas' source code cell-by-cell into the tables (hurrah for tables automatically applying formulas to entire columns). I had the foresight to periodically save my VBA modules and was able to import them. It took 2 days to rebuild the workbook (30 worksheets).

I refreshed all data connections, and populated each working sheet with at least 30 rows of key values to test the formulas and the resulting exports. Everything works and much faster too. When done, my new workbook was only 16 MB!

That is an incredible level of bloat. Can anyone explain how and why it got so bad? Can anyone offer suggestions of how to avoid such trouble in the future?

Comment: I have seen similar problems with corporate Office documents that have lived through several versions of Office and been bounced to and fro between a few different versions. The bloat usually seems to be orphaned metadata or simply images that are obscured by new ones plonked on top of them by clueless users using drag and drop. Worst case a file can almost double in size if the wind is blowing in the wrong direction. MSKB did once admit to this near exponential growth problem but ISTR the info has been erased. Sometimes save as HTML will allow you to eliminate (some of) the dross.

Comment: Hi @MartinBrown, Thank you for confirming my suspicions. I inherited this workbook from an intern who said he built it while teaching himself Excel. I have decades of experience with Excel, even teaching it for a year at a trade school,. The workbook is more complex than should be expected from someone learning it for the first time. Given the many hours of modifications he made over a 9-month period, it is little surprise that it suffered from his ministrations. My rebuilding it was best all around.